Error when i import the novnc library in my reactjs project
I want to incorporate novnc functionality on my reactjs project. First i installed the library using npm package manager using the above command:
npm install novnc --save

When im trying to import the RFB function from novnc to my App.js i come across to this error:

Any idea of how can i resolve this issue?

Change require to import, and ensure novnc dependence is included in your package.json.
